# SwiftUI: View with optional inner View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a `SwiftUI` view that may contain another view like this:

```
struct EmptyPlaceholderView<Header: View>: View {
    
    let header: Header?
    let text: LocalizedStringKey
    
    init(header: Header? = nil, text: LocalizedStringKey) {
        self.header = header
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            if let header = self.header {
                header
            }
            
            Text(text)
                .scaledFont(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.gray500)
        }
    }
    
}
```

this block of code compiles without problems, but when i try to call this view like this: `EmptyPlaceholderView(text: "No Data")` the compiler fires the following error:

`Generic parameter 'Header' could not be inferred`

how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made your view generic over `Header`, so even if the `header` property is `nil`, you must always specify the generic type.

You can use `EmptyView` for instance when you don't want to have a `Header`

```
EmptyPlaceholderView<EmptyView>(text: "No data")
```

Alternatively, you can add a new `init` which only takes a `text` parameter rather than giving `header` a `nil` default value. With generic type constraints on this new init, you won't have to specify the type of `Header` anymore, since it will be inferred as `EmptyView`.

```
init(text: LocalizedStringKey) where Header == EmptyView {
    self.header = nil
    self.text = text
}

init(header: Header?, text: LocalizedStringKey) {
    self.header = header
    self.text = text
}
```

Now `EmptyPlaceholderView(text: "No data")` compiles fine and creates a `EmptyPlaceholderView<EmptyView>`.

Answer (score 1):

For generics the type should always be specified (explicitly or inferring) during specialisation, so the possible solution is to have helper `init` for that, like

```
 init(text: LocalizedStringKey) where Header == EmptyView {
    self.init(header: nil, text: text)
 }
```